# Вопрос по .htaccess (RewriteRule)

Tags: .htaccess

Суть проблемы, когда я захожу по ссылке http://mysite.com/faq/1/?test1, всё работает хорошо... Но когда захожу к примеру по ссылке http://mysite.com/faq/1/, но даёт такую-же информацию, что и в 1 ссылке. Сам код:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^faq/([0-9]+)/?(.*)$ /faq.php?id=$1&json=true [L]
RewriteRule ^faq/([0-9]+)/$ /faq.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: А вы как обрабатываете параметр json=true? Что происходит с ним, при запрсе ссылки как в случае 2?

Comment: Если идёт параметр json=true, то faq.php передаёт ответ в виде json'a, а елси json=false - то html страница.

Comment: Это понятно. А он точно у вас правильно обрабатывается? Вы отладку делали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не сможете узнать таким способом что стоит после `?` (увидеть GET-параметры запроса):

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule On
RewriteRule ^(faq/.+)$ /faq.php?path=$1 [L]
```

faq.php:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Запрос `/faq/asdf/?foo=bar` выведет на экран `/faq/asdf/` (**не** `/faq/asdf/?foo=bar`).

Доступ к параметрам осуществляется с помощью конструкции `%{QUERY_STRING}`.
Соответственно, проверку на пустые параметры можно осуществить так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
```